# Scaling a set of objects

Tags: parent, groups

I am trying to create a shelf that scales properly. Each board in the shelf must be 1/2" thick and ideally I would be able to scale the depth, height and or length without affecting the 1/2" thickness of the boards. I have been able to achieve my goals by having separate objects for each board, selecting them together and scaling them (with the 1/2 dimension locked).

[image: shelf]

My question is: can I have a mesh that scales as desired? Or can I link these objects to scale as desired?

I have tried parent/child relationships, but they seem to ignore the 1/2 dimension lock. Also groups just seem to help you select the items within the group.

Are there any other suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Try http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66086/29586 for positioning and scaling the shelves automatically - you'd just need to position the top and bottom ones and the rest would be filled in. For the sides you could use Copy Location and Stretch To constraints so that they automatically fit to the sides.

Comment: Parent them all to a single empty and scale the empty would be my suggestion.

Comment: Parent them all to a single empty object didn't work (the object was the parent). That seems have a similar result to parenting to just one of the boards.

Comment: Ideally I would not have to rebuild the shelf every time I want  a different size, so although the distribute evenly suggestion is good, I don't think it fits my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this as another answer, instead of editing the above, because the method is completely different, more complete but also way more complex... you could choose this or the other method (or some other too) depending on different desired usage...

That said, this method:

- use separate meshed instead of a single one
- involves several and complex parenting and contraints
- allows "shelf scaling" on any axes X,Y,Z
- provides a separate "driver" mesh to enable the scaling on the "shelf" object

Because of the complex setup and being composed of separate meshes, this could be difficult to manipulate as a whole single "shelf" object... imho.

This is the example "shelf" (7 separate objects), and below you see the blue "driver" plane. To "scale" you MUST scale ONLY the "driver", along X, Y or Z.

[image]

here is the "scaling" along Z:

[image]

[image]

here is the "scaling" along X:

[image]

[image]

and here the "scaling" along Y:

[image]

[image]

here is the example .blend:

[image]

Note: due to the complex parenting/constraint setup, I think, sometimes the scaling can produce weird results, like separated planes, etc. In my experience you can "recover" those syncronization error issuing an "undo" step (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) just after it happens.

Maybe someone can improve this, but it seems to do what you were looking for, imho.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, what you could do is using hook to move one side of the shelf, like this

1. In edit mode, select all vertices of one side of the shelf, then, hook (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) them to an empty like this

[image]

2. then you can select the empty

[image]

3. and moving it (here on Y) will "scale horizontally" your shelf like this:

[image]

[image]

Other setups are possible, this is just to give you the idea

Comment: This looks pretty helpful. But I'm not sure I understand completely, is this a single mesh?

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you have an idea of how I could then scale the shelf vertically?

Comment: yes it is a single mesh: this works to preserve vertical dimensions while "scaling" horizontally. vertical is more difficult, for this kind of object. I think it could perhaps be done (differently) but I need to elaborate an example...

Comment: I added another answer (!) since I found a way, but quite different and more complex... hth.