# How to equally divide spacing between a set of objects?

Tags: objects

I have 5 different objects with different sizes. I want all the objects to have equally divided spacing between them. The red lines marking the spacing between them are big and small. How can I get equal spacing between them?

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: @atek Please remember to search the site first to see if the question has already been asked.

Comment: @ray thanks for replying there are 7 links and all have .py extension which file to download and install  https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/oscurart_tools/

Comment: @atek As the answers says, Oscurart Tools comes with blender, so you don't need to download anything. Also, comments regarding someone's answer should be on the answer itself, directed to the person who answered.

Comment: @RayMairlot its not working i have attach .gif image

Comment: As I said before, if you have questions regarding that answer, please place them under the answer, not to me. It is explained in the answer that the selection order is important, which there isn't much control over when using box select.

Comment: Hi, I just replied your question below my anwer there. :)