# How to quickly position many different objects (not copies of a single object) in rows with an offset?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

Does anyone know a tool or an addon to quickly position many different objects (not copies of a single object) in a scene in rows with an offset?

[image]

Why do I need it? I make a mod for a video game. The script for exporting models from the game is not very convenient, all models are placed in one scene at the origin. There are several hundreds of objects on each map, and what object does it represent, as we say, "you can't figure out without half a liter")). With the help of this solution, I can pretty quickly place all the objects in the scene so that I can navigate to what is

The question is closed, thanks

Comment: Must they be seperate objects? Or is it enough if it is a mesh?
Do you want to pick randomly from a selection of forms?

Comment: I have several dozen (hundreds, thousands) of objects in one scene, which are either located at one point, or randomly located in the scene. I need a tool to arrange these objects in a scene in several rows (as in the picture, for example)

Comment: Does sth speak agains the array modyfier?

Comment: As far as I know, the Array modifier creates an array of one object. and I have a lot of different objects

Comment: please edit your original question to claryfie that you want to clone *from a number of objects*

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/how-to-distribute-objects-evenly if objects already exist

Comment: Thanks, Mr Zak. It seems like what I need, but this addon does not want to work with my 2.79 blender (after selecting objects, pressing a button and selecting axes, nothing happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a particle systhem.

1. Group your objects in a collection
2. Create an plane with as many vertecies as you want to spawn objects.
3. Attach a particle systhem to this plane
4. Adjust the particle system to spawn all particles in the first frame.
5. Set the particle systhem to use the objects from the collection as particles.
6. Set the scale of the particles to 1

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try. can i make it in blender 2.79?

Comment: some things might be calld different (instead of collections you need to use grops) but it works the same.
dont forget to mark the question as answered and please clarifie your original question so people who search for it will be able to understand it without reading the comments first :)

Comment: It seems like what I need, but I do not understand how to save the result? I can not interact with these new objects "please clarifie your original question so people who search for it will be able to understand it without reading the comments first :)" - I don't understand what you mean. I use google translator (sorry for that)))

Comment: J.Doe, thanks a lot, this is what I need

Comment: In which way you want to *interact* with the new objects? 
Please describe your final goal in the original question. That makes it easier to answer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hm now that i understand what your final goal is, i have no answer.. you may ask around in the modding community that created the script. Ther is most likely a easyer way than trying to recompose the map from all exported objects. Gameangines usualy have there own optimizations like object instanzing (having an object in memory once but displaying it multiple times in a scenary). With the aproch i showed here thes optimizations wont work and you cann run into performance problems with bigger maps.