# Oscurart_tools show 'Needs at least two selected objects' when distribute objects in blender 2.91

Tags: add-on

My configuration:

```
ubuntu 20.04 
python 3.8.5 
blender 2.91
```

Followed this:

https://blenderartists.org/t/oscurart-tools-not-included-in-2-91/1267891

Clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/oscurart/Blender-28-Addons
```

And copy subfolder to addons:

```
sudo cp -r /home/alex/workspace/Thirdparty/Blender-28-Addons/oscurart_tools/ /usr/share/blender/2.91/scripts/addons
```

Then try to distribute 5 selected objects,but got error:

```
Needs at least two selected objects
```

and it seems this error occurred in old version.

https://blenderartists.org/t/oscurart-tools-update-rig-model-render-setting-more/576702/28

Comment: Hi please [edit] your question and add a [gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) or some images that detail the steps you are taking. Also see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/how-to-distribute-objects-evenly). Thanks :)

Comment: @Timaroberts,thanks for your suggestion,but for a blender user,my question is very clear already